# Remove last character in dbms_output.put_line

Tags: sql, oracle

How to remove last , character from the output

```
FOR v_rec IN (select COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE from cols where table_name = 'RFI_ATCH_CHKLST_DTL') LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line('p' || v_rec.COLUMN_NAME || ',');
END LOOP;
```

output is

```
pRACD_REMARKS,
pRACD_NA_STS,
pRACD_VAL2_STS,
pRACD_VAL_STS,
pBCLI_CODE,
pBAI_CODE,
pRAH_ID,
pRACD_ID,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly - you have no control over what has been written to the buffer. So you need to not write it in the first place. One way is to keep track of where you are in the output, the list of columns in this case, and only add the comma if you are not on the last item. Using the analytic `row_number()` function can be used for this:

```
begin
  for v_rec in (
    select column_name,data_type,
      row_number() over (order by column_id desc) as rn
    from user_tab_cols
    where table_name = 'RFI_ATCH_CHKLST_DTL'
    order by column_id
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put('p' || v_rec.column_name);
    if v_rec.rn != 1 then
      dbms_output.put(',');
    end if;
    dbms_output.new_line;
  end loop;
end;
/

pRACD_REMARKS,
pRACD_NA_STS,
pRACD_VAL2_STS,
pRACD_VAL_STS,
pBCLI_CODE,
pBAI_CODE,
pRAH_ID,
pRACD_ID
```

The `rn` pseudocolumn generates a numeric row counter, in descending order in this case. This is the reverse of the order the columns actually appear in - both `order by` clauses use the same value, `column_id`, with one descending and the other ascending:

```
select column_id, column_name,
  row_number() over (order by column_id desc) as rn
from user_tab_cols
where table_name = 'RFI_ATCH_CHKLST_DTL'
order by column_id;

 COLUMN_ID COLUMN_NAME                            RN
---------- ------------------------------ ----------
         1 RACD_REMARKS                            8 
         2 RACD_NA_STS                             7 
         3 RACD_VAL2_STS                           6 
         4 RACD_VAL_STS                            5 
         5 BCLI_CODE                               4 
         6 BAI_CODE                                3 
         7 RAH_ID                                  2 
         8 RACD_ID                                 1
```

So when the row counter goes down to 1, you know you're on the last row from the cursor, and you can use that knowledge to omit the comma.

You don't have to use `column_id` but it's probably useful here. You could order by `column_name`, or anything you like, as long as both clauses use the same ordering logic (but in reverse).